# Offline map in google-map-react

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, debugging

I use google-map-react and I want to load images from localhost and I have some problems. This is my code:

```
         <GoogleMapReact
            onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) =>
                map.mapTypes.set("roadmap", new maps.ImageMapType({
                    getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                        return "http://192.168.1.103/google/" + zoom + "/" +  coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png"
                    },
                    tileSize:new maps.Size(256,256),
                    name:"GoogleRoadMaps",
                    maxZoom:18
                }))
            }
            yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
            defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}>
            {
                this.state.childrenm
            }
        </GoogleMapReact>
```

But it doesn't work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible causes:

- 192.168.1.103 is your local area networt (LAN) IP address, which means it will only work if the WIFI of the client is connected to the same WIFI as the server and the machine is configured to allow connections on port 80.
- Content Security Policy(CSP) will need to be setup to upgrade the [http connection to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043719/) if the site is secure
- If a hardcoded URL does not work, then the [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081885/) may be configured incorrectly

Comment: it was Content Security Policy Problem ... Thanks!